# JS search function to show similar search results

Tags: javascript, search

I have about 100 terms (no number) saved as variable in js.

```
var terms = [ALL TERMS];
```

I have a simple search field: `<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">`

I am trying to make it so that when an user starts to type a letter, it automatically brings terms that matches what was typed.

I have seen this kind of function before. I would very much appreciate if someone could point me to a right direction in order to achieve this.

Thanks bunch!

Comment: Do you use jquery?

Comment: mhmm. I do use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a simple search, use the code below:

```
$("input").on("input",function(){
  for(var c in terms){ // loop through each item in terms
    if(terms[c].replace($(this).val(),"")!=terms[c])
      // the string matches your input
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and modify as needed. Thanks